# How valid positions in vector::insert()?

Tags: c++, vector, insert, codeblocks

```
 vector<int> vec = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
 vec.insert(vec.begin(),20);//valid 
 vec.insert(&vec[0],20);//invalid
```

what the different between vec.begin() and &vec[0]